# WSO2 identity server -javax.mail.MessagingException: 501 5.5.4 Invalid Address

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Hi I am using below smtp mail setting without password WSO2 5.7 output-event-adapters.xml and it was working fine. But same configuration in not working in WSO2 5.10 .

Please let me any setting I need configure for 5.10 wso2 ,smtp server without  password.

Email config

```
    <!-- Comment mail.smtp.user and mail.smtp.password properties to support connecting SMTP servers which use trust
    based authentication rather username/password authentication -->
    <property key="mail.smtp.from">do_not_reply@xxxx.com</property>

    <property key="mail.smtp.host">IP</property>
    <property key="mail.smtp.port">25</property>
    <!--property key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</property-->
    <!--property key="mail.smtp.auth">true</property-->
    <!-- Thread Pool Related Properties -->
    <property key="minThread">8</property>
    <property key="maxThread">100</property>
    <property key="keepAliveTimeInMillis">20000</property>
    <property key="jobQueueSize">10000</property>
```

Error in wso2 5.10 :

ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.email.EmailEventAdapter} - Event dropped at Output Adapter 'EmailPublisher' for tenant id '-1234', Error in message format, 501 5.5.4 Invalid Address
javax.mail.MessagingException: 501 5.5.4 Invalid Address

```
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueCommand(SMTPTransport.java:2324)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.helo(SMTPTransport.java:1678)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:746)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:366)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:246)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:195)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:254)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
    at org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.email.EmailEventAdapter$EmailSender.run(EmailEventAdapter.java:345)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Could you solve this problem? I'm facing the same error on version 5.11.0

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the steps in [1] to set up the email sending module in WSO2 IS 5.10.0?

You need to add the below configurations to the deployment.toml according to [1].

```
[output_adapter.email]
from_address= "wso2iamtest@gmail.com"
username= "wso2iamtest"
password= "Wso2@iam70"
hostname= "smtp.gmail.com"
port= 587
enable_start_tls= true
enable_authentication= true
```

[1] https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/setup/configuring-email-sending

Comment: Thanks quick Reply . Yes I tried .   [output_adapter.email]
from_address= "wso2iamtest@gmail.com"

hostname= "smtp.gmail.com"
port= 587
enable_start_tls= false
enable_authentication= false